# How to append date and timestamp in the Ansible log file?

Tags: ansible

How do I append date and timestamp in the Ansible log file?

Currently I have it as

```ini
log_path=/var/ansible-playbooks/ansible.log
```

in the `ansible.cfg`.

Everytime I run, I need this log to file to be saved with the timestamp like

```bash
ansible-20160808142400.log
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH` environment variable.

Execute playbook as follows:

```bash
ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=/tmp/ansible_$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S").log ansible-playbook myplabook.yml
```

Alternatively you can [write your own](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#callback-plugins) [Callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html) that will log what you want and where you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running on a UNIX based system you can take advantage of the behavior of inodes. Define a log path in your ansible.cfg. I created a directory in $HOME/.ansible.

```
log_path = $HOME/.ansible/log/ansible.log
```

Create a pre-task section in your playbooks and include the following task:

```
- name: Create the log file for this run
  shell: /bin/bash -l -c "mv {{ lookup('env', 'HOME') }}/.ansible/log/ansible.log  {{ lookup('env', 'HOME') }}/.ansible/log/ansible.log-{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S') }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ lookup('env', 'USER') }}"
```

When ansible starts running a playbook it creates the log file and starts writing to it. The log file is then renamed to ansible.log-YYYYmmddHHMMSS and the ansible process continues to write to it because even though the log file's name has changed the inode associated with it hasn't.