# How to set log file name to playbook name in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, devops

Is there a way to set the Ansible log file name dynamically to the playbook name that is running?

I've tried to use `ansible.cfg` for that, but that doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

From your few description I guess you are interested in [Logging Ansible output](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html) to

> "*save Ansible output in a single log on the Control Node, set the `log_path` [configuration file setting](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_configuration.html#intro-configuration)*"

and by using the playbook file name, right?

Please take note that those configuration parameters were not mentioned to be dynamic. So except from setting environment variables

```bash
# Run
export NAME='test'; ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=~/test/${NAME}.log ansible-playbook ${NAME}.yml
```

there seems to be no other options.

```bash
# View log
~/test$ cat ${NAME}.log
```

Or maybe renaming the generated log file afterwards to the playbook name.

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: How can I set log file name dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33474056/6771046)
- [How to append date and timestamp in the Ansible log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39457773/6771046)
- [Where is Ansible's default log path and is it possible to log operation on Remote Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70504418/6771046)